# ON DUPLICATE помощь

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Почему это не работает? Не могу даже поменять первичные ключи, почему у меня при добавление поля price ставиться первичный ключ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 string sql = "INSERT INTO items (Name, Href, Price) VALUES (@title, @href, @price1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Price`=VALUES(`Price`);";
```

upd
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "ставиться первичный ключ" и что означает "добавление поля price", оно же и так уже есть в таблице

Comment: @Mike когда я добавил в таблицу поле Price, поле создалось, и в отличии от других у него подсвечивается ключ "Первичный". Я думал может в этом проблема.

Comment: Да, разглядел картинку ... удалите поле price и создайте для начала первичный ключ на поле `id`, ему там самое место. Вообще ключи сами по себе не появляются, вы должны были сами при добавлении поля указать что оно первичный ключ, что бы так стало. И еще вам надо сделать уникальный индекс/ключ на после href (вы же вроде хотели делать обновление на основе него. Да, и поле Price делать double я бы не рекомендовал, деньги нельзя хранить в этом типе данных, он же не гарантирует полную точность числа. Используйте decimal соответствующего размера

Comment: @Mike когда пытаюсь делать href индексом/ключом  пишет примерно вот такое  BLOB/TEXT column 'Href' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Господи, а text то оно зачем. Используйте varchar и да, укажите при его создании максимальную длину которой оно может быть

Comment: @Mike все поменял как вы написали, но как добавляю price все равно первичным стает(можно было указать при создании primary, unique,index,fulltex). Посмотрите новый скрин

Comment: Я эти картинки не понимаю. у вас внизу написано что первичный id. почему там справа что то светится не понятно. у меня phpmyadmin под руками нет что бы посмотреть. если вам копейки нужны сделайте price (10,2). И просто попробйте добавить две записи с одинаковым price, если добавятся значит в ок если нет - то поле действительно стало уникальным.

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо, все меняется